# Importing Swift into module Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridge

I have a project written in Swift, and I'm using a 3rd-party library written in Objective-C that needs to import AppDelegate.h.

How do I expose the Swift AppDelegate.Swift?

I've tried annotating AppDelegate with `@objc`, and important with `#import <People/People-Swift.h>` and also tried #import "People-Swift.h"``.

Comment: Why would a third party library expects you to import `AppDelegate.h` that must be a very poorly written library than get rid of it n look for new library. Why its poor u ask? How can third part library writer can expect the UIApplications delegate name be AppDelegate what if I name it as MyAppDelegate than third party code wont work ? Moreover AppDelegate file outside the package of third party library how can library expect the file or any property in perticular file outside its package ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/blob/master/ios/RNAppAuth.m I can't control what others do I'm afraid

Comment: So this library expects you to have a property named `currentAuthorizationFlow` in your appDelegate ? What if I wanna move this method somewhere else ? Like some other SIgnleton instance of mine then ?? That wont be possible because this library expects u to have this property ? Thats really poor way of creating library

Comment: Ok yeah but do you know how to expose the swift appdelegate to the libraries objective-c?

Comment: gimme sometime lemme check n update